# How do I disable cronjob for particular time interval

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have  a cronjob that run every mins daily. I have a requirement to stop it from particular time eg: 2pm on Saturday till 10am Monday. How can this be implemented

Answer (score 0):

You should define explicit the time when you want to be run. And because of timeframe this can't be done by one line. Something like can do the job:

```
* * * * 2-5 /path/to/script
* 0-13 * * 6 /path/to/script
* 10-23 * * 1 /path/to/script
```

first line will run it every minute from Tuesday to Friday

second line will run it every minute till 14h on Saturday

third line will run it every minute starting from 10h on Monday